# Store an Image efficiently in a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, image, compression

I currently writing a program that creates and fills Controls in a WPF application from a XML file. One of the features are that the User can choose a image he wants to display in the program. This image is displayed in a Image Control. After choosing the image, the program saves all data back to the XML file.

The image is converted and saved as follows:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
System.Drawing.Image image = new Bitmap(sPathOfImage);

image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
bytes = ms.ToArray();
XElement Image = new XElement("Image", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));

xDocument.Add(Image);
xDocument.Save("xDocument.xml");
```

And this works perfectly, all's fine. However, main **problem is the length of the value of the XElement Image**. Even for 40kb images the lenght is 60,000 signs. And for a 9mb image it needs huge 13,200,000 signs. And now I'm looking for a way better solution to store images in the XML file.

Through specifications it has to be in one XML file.

So, is there a good way to make the string smaller, a more suitable stream, anything I'm missing out? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Use a different format, not `BMP`, but perhaps `JPEG`. That would save *a lot*.

Comment: If the image is already compressed, I don't think you'll be able to shorten the string much. You could split the "signs" into several chunks.

Comment: Is it a must to keep the image file within the XML. Would not be enought to keep within the XML a relative path or URL to the file and distribute the file together with the XML?

Comment: And please note that the first line of your sample code is completely redundant. You could write `byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray()`.

Comment: I tried different types, but it is the same thing everytime. The lenght is just way too long.

Comment: Then the requirement should be changed and the image saved in an external binary file.

Comment: @YaugenVlasau: It is indeed a must. I WISH I could do it the way you said.

Comment: @Synced Someone who writes down a requirement stating that an image file as large as 9 MB should be stored in an XML file has absolutely no idea what he's talking about. The requirement is nonsense and must be changed, seriously.

Comment: @Clemens: To be honest, I already guessed that this is not a proper solution, but I never imagined that it would be so bad. I completely agree with you.

Comment: There's no way it takes up the same number of bytes in `JPEG` format as it does in `BMP`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No magic will happen about filling an image content into XML file. The content will be proportional to the original file size. Even zipping the file and saving it to the XML will not help, because there are images with lower possibilities to be compressed.
For evaluation purposes, I decided to find out how Visual Studio keeps the image in its resource file. The result is the following:

- VS puts the image under Resource folder
- in Resource.resx puts a reference to the image

..

```
  <data name="_myimage" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>Resources\myimage.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
```

Maybe would it make sense to stop reinventing the wheel, and believe the professionals? :)

Comment: Haha, thanks for the effort, guess this is the final evidence. :D Since I'm not able to find any other/better solution, I'm going to accept this. It cannot be helped.

Answer (score 3):

**To store image into XML file:**

1. Read all the bytes into memory using `File.ReadAllBytes()`.
2. Convert the bytes to a Base64 string using `Convert.ToBase64String()`
3. Write the Base64 Encoded string to your element content.

**To retrieve the image from XML file:**

```
 string val = currentXml.Element("image").Value; 
 byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(val); 
 MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(bytes); 
 Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(mem);
```